# Change UIImageView alpha state on tap

Tags: ios, gesture, alpha, tap

Wish to change UIimageview alpha with tap gesture, for example:

Tap - change alpha to 0.5f 
Tap again - alpha back to 1 state

Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

Attach a tap gesture recognizer to the view:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(yourFunction:)];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

then in the gesture recognizer's handler:

```
if (imageView.alpha > 0.5f){
    imageView.alpha = 0.5f;
}
else {
    imageView.alpha = 1.0;
}
```

Comment: I want to know, do you need call `- (CGRect)rectForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` after change the alpha value of the imageView in UITableViewCell.